# Cambiar una cadena de texto Laravel

Tags: laravel-blade

Me han encargado cambiar un texto de una página web, dicha página está hecha a través de Laravel. He podido realizar algunas modificaciones de diseño aún sin saber nada de Laravel, pero me he topado con esto que no puedo solucionar.

Este es el código:

```
<main id='cuerpo'>
    <?php $rutasNoBanner = ['privacidad', 'buscadorPost', 'buscadorGet', 'verAyuda'];?>
    @if (!in_array(Route::current()->getName(), $rutasNoBanner))
        <div class='@if (Route::current()->getName() == 'sobre-nosotros')sobre-nosotros @endif' id='banner'>
            <section class='container cabecera'>
                <h1 id='h1'>@yield('tituloSeccion')</h1>
                <p class='texto-cabecera-movil'>@yield('textoCabeceraMovil') </p>
                <a title="{{__('sobre-nosotros.paginaSobreNosotros')}}" class="enlace-sobre-nosotros"
                    href="/{{ $locale }}/sobre-nosotros">{{__('general.sobreNosotros')}}</a>
                <p class='enlace-contacto' onclick='abre_capa_contacto();'>{{__('general.contacto')}}</p>
                <p class='boton' onclick='abre_capa_solicita();'>{!! __('general.textobotonInicio') !!}</p>
            </section>
```

Quiero cambiar el texto del "h1" pero no consigo encontrar donde se ubica `@yield('tituloSeccion')`, No sé si con esta información es suficiente, pero la idea es encontrar de donde saca el texto ese `@yield` para poder modificarla.

**Edit:** Este es el comienzo de `layout.blade.php` que es donde está el `h1` que quiero modificar

```
<?php $locale = app()->getLocale(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ $locale }}">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<head>
    <title>***** | {{__('general.inicioTitulo')}}</title>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
    <meta content='***** | {{__('general.inicioTitulo')}}' name='title'>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta content='IE=Edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <meta content='telephone=no' name='format-detection'>
```

Estos son los archivos BLADE que creo que es de donde se puede sacar esa información. Todo lo que he podido cambiar lo he hecho desde layout.blade.php:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la carpeta views:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El @yield le indica al template que debe buscar la sección `tituloSeccion` en el template que implementa esa vista. Es decir, en la carpeta de vistas tendrás otra carpeta que tiene un `@extends(nombreDeLaVistaQueEstásModificando)`, y que será la que tiene definido eso como `@section('tituloSeccion')`. Una manera rápida de encontrar dicha vista sería usar el IDE que uses para hacer una búsqueda precisamente de ese tag `@section`.

Comment: La he encotrado es inicio.blade.php y aparece esto: `@section('tituloSeccion', __('general.inicioTituloBody'))`  pero ahí tampoco aparece ninguna cadena que pueda modificar

Comment: La aplicación está escrita con soporte para varios idiomas, `__()` es un *magic method* para traducir. En algún lado debes tener un json con la clave `general.inicioTituloBody` que se está leyendo ahí. Es decir, al usar el método `__('general.inicioTituloBody')` lo que está haciendo laravel es buscar esa clave (general.inicioTituloBody) en el archivo de traducciones del idioma que le toque devolver, automáticamente. Simplemente encuentra el fichero, modifica el literal y listo.

Answer (score 0):

debes buscar dentro del árbol de carpetas del gestor de plantillas de Laravel
" resources/view " tiene que estar definida por ahí la directiva Yield

deberias compatir  el codigo completo del archivo  blade , para saber desde donde se extiende o cual es su archivo archivo  contendor , ya que , en esos archivos padres deberioa estar el valor de la directiva   Yield

suerte

Comment: Tu respuesta seria mas clara si le dieras una explicacion de como mas o menos seria el codigo a cambiar, con decir en que carpeta esta solo le creas la duda de que cambiar, con decir "debe estar definida por ahi" no ayuda mucho

Comment: se entiende asi ?